# Trying to load a responsive CSS media query using Custom Taxonmy

Tags: css, responsive

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .page-id-9334 .site-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

I am trying to load this CSS into Custom Taxonomy Pages...

My original question refers to a specific Page ID (and I edited my original question).

Anyways - based upon the replies below I thought that this would work but it throws an error, with or without the `<style>` CSS Opening Tags.

Can anyone else please shed some light on how I might be able to get this to work?

Thanks!

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
    if ( is_tax(country) ) {

      <style>
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .site-content {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column-reverse;
        }
      }
      </style>

    }
} );
```

Comment: Are you saying that the code is added on every page and you just want it on page 9334? How you added that code - via a hook like `wp_head`?

Comment: Yes correct - it is added into wp_head so it loads throughout the site but of course should only work on Page ID 9334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there are a few elements missing

First is the quotes in `is_tax(country)`, should be is_tax('country')

Second you are missing closing and opening PHP tags

When working with action that require html output you can do it in a few ways.
For now we will stick with the method you wanted to use.

The final result would look like this

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
  if ( is_tax('country') ) {
?>
  <style>
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .site-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
  }
  </style>
<?php
  }
} );
```

Comment: thanks works great

Answer (score 0):

You said (via the comments) that you added the code via [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/), so if you want the code be added only on the Page (post type `page`) with the ID of 9334, you can use [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) which is one of the [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) in WordPress.

So for example:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
    if ( is_page( 9334 ) ) {
        // add your CSS here
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for that but unfortuntely that threw an error. Also - my original question was wrong, I need this to load on Custom Taxonomy - sorry for the confusion

Comment: Sorry for the simplified example, I thought you'd know that you need to close the PHP block of code before outputting a HTML, i.e. `?>HTML here<?php`, without using string concatenation like `echo 'this' . ' string ' . 'is <i>concatenated</i>';`.