# Combine page types and Custom Taxonomy in a functions.php command

Tags: functions, css

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
  if ( is_tax('country') ) {
?>
  <style>
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .site-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
  }
  </style>
<?php
  }
} );
```

The above works great thanks to the folks who helped me here: [Trying to load a responsive CSS media query using Custom Taxonmy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/382701/trying-to-load-a-responsive-css-media-query-using-custom-taxonmy/382708#382708)

What I am trying to do is also combine the above to include a Page-ID 9399

Do I do this by using two pipes like this "||" or "&&"?

I tried the below and (oddly) it doesn't seem to work?

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
  if( is_tax('country') || is_page('9399') ){
?>
  <style>
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .site-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
  }
  </style>
<?php
  }
} );
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you want the style in taxonomy country and for the taxonomy with the id 9399 you will need to change || for && and instead of is_page, use is_tax

Comment: Ah no, what I mean is that the Page ID 9399 is outside of the taxonomy, I mean it is a regular "Page"

Comment: So, there are two things that I need to apply this CSS > to the entire custom taxonomy AND that stand alone page...thanks for all help

Comment: You're doing it correctly, if you're checking if the current page is a taxonomy archive page *or* a post of the `page` type. But I suggest you to check the page's source code and see if your CSS is actually added there - if it is, then it means you'll need to change your CSS so that it works for both the taxonomy and Page.

Comment: thanks that worked!